# MVC Parameterized Element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view which I want to display a different type of HTML element based on a property of the model. The solution I've come up with is:

```
@if (Model.Element == "span")
{
    <span>
        Some stuff
    </span>
}
else if (Model.Element == "p")
{
    <p>
        Some stuff
    </p>
}
else
{
    <div>
        SomeStuff
    </div>
}
```

This is obviously not very extensible. I'd like to write something like:

```
<@Model.Element>
    Some stuff
</@Model.Element>
```

but it doesn't seem to be allowed. Is there any way to do something like this.

(I appreciate that this goes somewhat against the grain of MVC as the model and therefore the controller is specifying HTML. Actually, the element type comes from the parent view, so I think this is okay.)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.Raw("<" + Model.Element + ">")
Some Stuff
@Html.Raw("</" + Model.Element + ">")
```

Is about as simple as possible. Though you could always use the `TagBuilder`:

```
@{
  TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder(Model.Element);
  tb.InnerHtml = "Some Stuff";
  @Html.Raw(tb.ToString())
}
```

Comment: Brad's answer is right, but I invite you on reflecting about separation of concerns. MVC pattern should be about "separating Model from View from Controller". Having a presentation detail stuck on the Model breaks this principle.

Comment: Brad - thanks. Only drawback with those is that Intellisense won't realize that you're inside and element, but I guess I can live with that.

Claudio - as I said, the actual information comes from the parent view and is only being relayed through the model and the controller. Is there another way to transfer information from a parent to a child view? I don't think ViewBag will work, since I may have multiple instances of the partial view in a single page.